# Revert change made to AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

So our AWS is manually configured. Is there a way to revert some change that was done recently to a security group, or to see a history of changes?

Comment: Do you have cloudtrail enabled?

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.

However, I think that you first need to configure AWS Config to start recording the history of your resources. If you haven't activated it, then it will not be able to provide a history of changes.

Comment: no, sadly it wasn't activated